# Iterator gives different results based on usage c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

I recently started c++ programming. I shifted from Java.
I was building my own Iterable class template like this:

```
template<class T> class Iterable
    {
        T start,stop;
    public:
        explicit Iterable(T s,T e) {start=s; stop=e;;}


    public:
        virtual void next(T& i) =0;
    public:
        class iterator: public std::iterator<
        std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
        T,                      // value_type
        long,                      // difference_type
        const T*,               // pointer
        T                       // reference
        >{
            T current;
            Iterable<T>* obj;
        public:
            explicit iterator(T t,Iterable<T>* o) : obj(o) {current=t;}
            iterator& operator++() {obj->next(current); return *this;}
            iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
            bool operator==(iterator other) const {return current == other.current;}
            bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
            const T& operator*() const {return current;}
        };
        iterator begin() {return iterator(start,this);}
        iterator end() {return iterator(stop,this);}
    };
```

When i tried to use this iterator, I got different results when invoked differently:

```
for(auto S=SI.begin();S!=SI.end();S++)
    {
        cout << *S << "\n";
        //cout << contains(seqs,S) << "\n";
        if(!contains(seqs,*S))
            seqs.push_back(*(new Sequence(*S)));
    }
```

gave different results from:

```
for(Sequence S : SI)
    {
        cout << S << "\n";
        //cout << contains(seqs,S) << "\n";
        if(!contains(seqs,S))
            seqs.push_back(*(new Sequence(S)));
    }
```

even in the loop.
My SeqIter class (SI is object of this class) is as follows:

```
class SeqIter : public flex::Iterable<Sequence>
{
    int n;
public:
    SeqIter(int s) : Iterable(Sequence(copyList(0,s),s),Sequence(copyList(3,s),s)) {n=s;}

    void next(Sequence& s)
    {
        char ch;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ch=nextBase(s[i]);
            s[i]=ch;
            if(ch!=0)
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Sorry if this is too much code, but I do not know how much code is required.

---

Also, a brief explanation on the Sequence class:
It is a class that has an array of numbers (in this case I tried with 3), and it generates next sequences based on the first, i.e. 000, 100, 200, 300; 010,110 ... 
Each digit ranges from 0-3 (both included)
I am unable to understand why both loops give different sequences (first gives 000 100 200 300 **010** 110 whereas second gives 000 100 200 300 **000** 110)
I thought both the loops were fundamentally same, and that the first was just the expansion of the second. Is that not so?

Also sequence class: (Sorry for delay, but I guess this is the problem)

```
class Sequence
{
    int size=1;
    char* bps;
public:
    Sequence() {size=0;}
    Sequence(int s) 
    {
        size=s;
        bps=new char[s];
    }
    Sequence(char* arr,int s)
    {
        size=s;
        bps=arr;
    }
    Sequence(const Sequence& seq)
    {
        size=seq.size;
        bps=new char[size];
        strcpy(bps,seq.bps);
    }

    String toString() const {return *(new String(bps,size));}
    inline char* toCharArray() {return bps;}
    inline int getSize() const {return size;}

    //operator overloading
public:
    bool operator==(const Sequence& s2) const
    {
        if(s2.size!=size)
            return false;
        String r1=toString();
        String r2=s2.toString();
        return (r1==r2 || r1==r2.reverse());
    }
    inline bool operator!=(const Sequence& s2) const {return !operator==(s2);}
    const char& operator[](int n) const
    {
        if(n>=size)
            throw commons::IndexOutOfBoundsException(n,size);
        return bps[n];
    }
    char& operator[](int n)
    {
        if(n>=size)
            throw commons::IndexOutOfBoundsException(n,size);
        return bps[n];
    }
    Sequence& operator=(const Sequence& seq)
    {
        size=seq.size;
        bps=new char[size];
        strcpy(bps,seq.bps);
    }
};
```

Comment: _"but I do not know how much code is required"_ A [mcve] is required, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I see three places you have code like `*(new Sequence(*S))`. That is a memory leak. You allocate memory for an object, dereference the pointer to make a copy, and then the original object is leaked. Your `Sequence` class also calls `new[]` in several places but there's no destructor or `delete[]`. You need to learn about resource management because it looks like your code is leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: `seqs.push_back(*(new Sequence(S)));` C++ is not Java. You don't need `new` just to make an object. What you've written is an all-in-one memory leak.

Comment: This is a common pitfall that people who come over from Java fall into. Java has no `delete`, and the syntax is deceptively similar to C++, and `new` is always used to create new objects. Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Thanks. I had this question too. Where do I put my delete[]s?

Comment: To move from Java to C++: (1) stop using `new`.  I mean never use it.  A full program can contain 0 `new`s in C++14 and beyond.  Create values, not pointers.  (2) you are responsible for everything's lifetime.  (3) Learn the rule of 0/3/5.  Learn RAII.  Do not put references in class's or structs.

Comment: You "put your delete"s where they need to be put. You need to figure out when and where your objects are no longer needed, then delete them. It's up to you to figure it out. Java does it for you, but not C++. In C++ you have full control over your destiny. You have to understand automatic scope, global scope, and dynamic scope, in order to have a firm grasp of object lifetimes in C++.

Comment: Herb Sutter's YouTube video on "Leak Freedom in C++" is 1:40 well spent if you want to learn about C++ memory management https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=11s

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone. Answering my own question after debugging:
In my Sequence class, I was using strcpy in copying char*, where the array did not end with a '\0'
Probably that caused the error:
I read online a bit more to find that the expansion was as follows:

```
for(Sequence S : seqs)
{
...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for(auto i=SI.begin();i!=SI.end();i++)
{
Sequence S=*i;
...
}
```

So in the assignment, (S=*i) the data was not properly copied.
Sorry for all the trouble

fixed by removing assignment operator overload, and changing copy-constructor to:

```
Sequence(const Sequence& seq)
{
        size=seq.size;
        bps=new char[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            bps[i]=seq[i];
}
```